# 2D PostProcessing plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, contour, post-processing

I want to plot my thermal analysis results on a 2D mesh. I have a 2xN matrix named "coord", which basically has the X and Y coordinates of the nodes of my mesh. At each node, I have a temperature value which is saved as a 1xN matrix. How do I plot a heatmap or a contour plot for my results?

Comment: `surf(x,y,z)` will do, being x and y colums of coord, as long as they represent a meshgrid

Comment: Surf fucntion expects a matrix of minimum size 2x2.. Where as my temperatures are saved as "nodeDisp" which is a 1xN vector. "Error using surf (line 71)
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector."

Comment: Well, not really, you have a `1x(MxO)` vector where `M*O=N`. Just `reshape` `x,y,z` to be 2D